# Recommended programmer for parallel flash memory?

Tags: programmer, flash

Can you recommend a programmer for low voltage parallel flash memories like 29LV320? 
(around 100 USD max, if possible:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a [True-USB PRO GQ-4X Willem Programmer](http://www.mcumall.com/comersus/store/comersus_viewItem.asp?idProduct=4282) with SMD adapters about 150 USD. It can do everything I need:)

Answer (score 1):

I've used ChipMax from www.eetools.com for EPROMs. I think it will program parallel flash memory as well. It was around $100. It works pretty well.

EDIT: OK maybe it's closer to $\$$300 than $\$$100. It's much less expensive than the other monster programmer we have which was over $\$$1000 and doesn't really work any better.

Comment: I also like my ChipMax.  But the OP needs to keep in mind that it requires a parallel port.  It works in XP just fine, but I haven't tried Windows 7 yet.

Comment: I've googled on this ChipMax but unfortunately it's around $300

Answer (score 0):

Will [Xeltek SUPERPROZ](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=415-1000-ND) do it? $200 plus any adapter for the package.